# Split null or space on the first of a string?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm getting a string `"    abc df fd"`;
I want to split a space or null of string. As result is `"abc df fd"` That such I want;

```
 private string _senselist;
    public string senselist
    {
        get
        {
            return _senselist;
        }
        set
        {
            _senselist = value.Replace("\t", "").Replace("&nbsp;"," ").Split(,1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `var strings = senselist.Split(" ");`? You need to provide a full string in order for us to try and help. I see no tabs in your string yet you replace "\t".

Comment: I'm very confused by what you're trying to do; are you just trying to remove leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the first space? You seem to be saying the original string is " abc df fd" and that what you want is simply "abc df fd". Is that right?

Comment: The `Replace("&nbsp;"," ")` concerns me; if the input is HTML, you should be using a HTML-decode step - not just converting one entity

Answer (score 5):

To remove spaces from the begining and the ending of a `string`, you can use [`Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string data = "    abc df fd";
string trimed = data.Trim(); // "abc df fd"
```

On your code add `Trim` at the end, instead of `Split`

```
_senselist = value.Replace("\t", "").Replace("&nbsp;"," ").Trim();
```

As @andrei-rînea recommended you can also check [`TrimStart(' ')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TrimEnd(' ')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: To add a little bit on the great answer above, if you need to remove spaces just from beginning or just at the end you can use TrimStart or TrimEnd.